# Google Street and AR

Tags: augmented-reality

I am looking forward to connect google street view with augmented reality application. I am looking forward for some development framework, using which i can connect google street view in an AR application. Basically i have to get some values from database which will have address or lat/long of restaurants and i have to identify these restaurants on google street view using augmented reality. How can it be done? Are there some frameworks in place? I have gone through String, Vuforia and metoia. I am not sure how can google street view be integrated with Vuforia. Looks like String and metoia in AR are not selling licenses any more.

Answer (score 0):

Vuforia and similar SDKs are basically marker-based AR libraries - they are used for detecting images that are known in advance and may be recognized by the SDK.

From your description, you seem to need a geo-location based AR. Although I'm not sure this is exactly what you want, I suggest you take a look at mixare (which is also open source): [mixare](http://www.mixare.org/)